# nullptr initial value and WinAPI NULL return

Tags: c++, c++11, null-pointer, nullptr

If I initialize a variable with a value of nullptr.
and then I fetch a WinAPI function in to it that may return a value NULL on failure, do I have to use NULL or can I still check nullptr when checking what ever the function failed or not?

```
if ( windowfunctionresult == nullptr )
{
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr):

> The keyword `nullptr` denotes the pointer literal. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. There exist implicit conversions from `nullptr` to null pointer value of any pointer type and any pointer to member type. Similar conversions exist for any null pointer constant, which includes values of type `std::nullptr_t` as well as the macro `NULL`.

So `nullptr` and `NULL` will behave the same in the context of checking whether a pointer is null.

But you can also simply rely on the pointer-to-`bool` conversion:

```
if ( !windowfunctionresult )
{
  return false;
}
```